# Pip install for Astroscrappy. Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, installation

When i am trying to install astroscrappy in my Linux Mint 19 system with command `pip install astroscrappy`, giving error that below

```
Collecting astroscrappy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/12/899e09a3dee9055fb1428c22a42ca65e24242c4491a30de982af38cea792/astroscrappy-1.0.5.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    OpenMP was not found. astroscrappy will be compiled without OpenMP. (Use the "-v" option of setup.py for more details.)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-5apIDa/astroscrappy/setup.py", line 77, in <module>
        package_info = get_package_info()
      File "/tmp/pip-build-5apIDa/astroscrappy/astropy_helpers/astropy_helpers/setup_helpers.py", line 396, in get_package_info
        ext_modules.extend(setuppkg.get_extensions())
      File "astroscrappy/utils/setup_package.py", line 104, in get_extensions
        '(End of OpenMP info)').format(*outputs))
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 71: ordinal not in range(128)

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5apIDa/astroscrappy/
```

What should i do?

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: `$ python --version`
Output:
`Python 2.7.15rc1`

Comment: Looks like an issue in the script not accounting for non ascii characters in the return of the `check_openmp` function. I would suggest you comment the line that is causing the issue and try to recompile

Comment: Before installation command, i just wrote that and fixed it.
`export LC_ALL=C`